# Unable to find chat room to move posts

Tags: bug, chat, russian-stackoverflow

I can't find a room called "[Урна](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52936/)" (Russian analog of "[Trash](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19718/trash)" room) when want to move posts away from [main Stack Overflow in Russian chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--):

> [image: move posts]

Does search engine support only Latin names?

Comment: True. Any non-English letter/character is simply ignored, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDV52.png). (so having only non-English cause all rooms to appear.)

Comment: seems like nobody cares :)